# C++ template not compiling when passing through function signature

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following, minimal example (compiles without `#1` and `#2`):

```
void foo(void)
{ }

template<typename T> class Stage2;

template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct Stage2<Ret (Args...)>
{
    template<Ret (*func)(Args...)>
    static void foobar(void)
    { /* Do something */ }
};

template<typename FuncType>
struct Stage1
{
    template<FuncType func>
    static void bar(void)
    {
        Stage2<FuncType>::foobar<func>();       // #1, Not working
        Stage2<decltype(func)>::foobar<func>(); // #2, Not working
        Stage2<void()>::foobar<func>();         // #3, Working
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Stage1<decltype(foo)>::bar<foo>();
    return 0;
}
```

Why does it not compile with `#1` and `#2`, whereas it compiles just fine with `#3`? In my opinion, `#3` should be equivalent to the others as long as foo has the signature `void()`, which it does in this example. Even the compiler tells me, that `FuncType` is in fact `void()` (see below).

Error message (the same for `#1` and `#2`):

```
main.cpp: In static member function ‘static void Stage1<FuncType>::bar()’:
main.cpp:21:40: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
         Stage2<FuncType>::foobar<func>();       // #1, Not working
                                        ^
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘static void Stage1<FuncType>::bar() [with FuncType func = foo; FuncType = void()]’:
main.cpp:29:37:   required from here
main.cpp:21:33: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘void (*)()’ to binary ‘operator<’
         Stage2<FuncType>::foobar<func>();       // #1, Not working
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
```

What am I missing here? I'm using g++ 7.2.0.

Note: I'm not really interested if this is useful in any way, I'd just like to know why it doesn't compile because it makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, what's going on is this:

```
Stage2<FuncType>::foobar<func>();
```

contains a dependent name (depending on FuncType), therefore you have to follow the correct C++-syntax for calling member templates (thus the syntax error messages), which is

```
Stage2<FuncType>::template foobar<func>();
```

Note that this does not apply for `Stage2<void()>::foobar<func>();` as there is no dependent name involved.

The same applies to `Stage2<decltype(func)>::foobar<func>();`, but this alone still won't fix it as there is some tricky obstacle. According to §14.1.8 [temp.param],

> A non-type template-parameter of type “array of T” or “function returning T” is adjusted to be of type “pointer to T” or “pointer to function returning T”, respectively.

`decltype(func)` will be `void(*)()` instead of `void()` (even though `FuncType` was specified to be `void()`), so no function type but pointer to function type will be passed as template parameter to `Stage2` for which there is no specialization provided (as `Stage2<Ret (Args...)>` and `Stage2<Ret (*)(Args...)>` are not the same), thus falling back to the default template declaration, finally yielding a "use of incomplete type" error.

Comment: Why is `decltype(foo)` considered a non-type template parameter?